# Adding and subtracting values based on checkboxes

Tags: checkbox, google-sheets-formula

I am creating a sheet to calculate points earned throughout the week and then subtract at the end of the week based on if a checkbox is marked.
So the columns represent days 1-7 of the week. I want it to add 10 pts to the total every time a checkbox is marked in days 1-7.
Then when the "end of week" box is checked, it subtracts 70 points.

I did countif but that adds ones. Not the value of 10. I could not get a sumif to work.
Thank you!

Comment: If I understood correctly, you can multiply countif result by 10. If not then post some sample data or share GS.

Comment: Duh! That worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: To subtract 70 when the "end of week" box is checked, I tried this =COUNTIF((B4:H4), "true")*10 AND COUNTIF((J4),"true") *-7   and also tried this =COUNTIF((B4:H4), "true")*10 AND COUNTIF((J4),"true") -70)

Comment: Are you saying those worked, or you still have an unresolved question?  If so, please share a sample sheet with some data, and the results you want to get from that data.